# Limiting and/or automatically changing value for number input fields

Tags: android, knockout.js, input, foreach

I am working on a minigolf app for Android, and I am using knockout foreach bindings to display 18 rows of input number fields where users can insert there numbers of hits they needed for each hole.

My first requirement is that I want those input fields to behave so that when the user enters "9", it should automatically change to 10 (because the rules for the minigolf say that if the user uses more than 8 hits, the hole should be counted as 10).

My second requirement is that it's possible to type in numbers higher than 10 at the moment. I have to specify that you can't type in numbers higher than 10 into the input fields.

Anyone who got any idea to solve my requirements?

This is my ko foreach:

```html
<!-- ko foreach: rounds -->
<input class="input-block-level" 
       name="number" 
       type="number" 
       value="" 
       data-bind="value: hits,valueUpdate: 'keyup'" 
       maxlength="2" 
       min="1" 
       max="10"/>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Perhaps the [knockout-validation plugin](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation) is of interest.

Comment: If the hit/stroke count is capped at 10, you could use a different UI control (+/-, slider) to enforce the restrictions by not directly exposing a text-based input field.

Comment: I hoped it could be accomplished from the html file in form of javascript instead of inside the knockout

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by using javascript to check up on fields both for the number 9 and number greater than 10, both will turn into number 10, so now the app works as it should

Answer (score 0):

You could subscribe to your `hits` observable to check the value to decide whether you trigger further actions or not. Check out the [official documentation about subscribers](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html).

Comment: I have subscribed to the hits but I can't get the number out of my ko.observable(hits)

Comment: I assume that you have declared the observable  `self.hits = ko.observable()` in your view model. Now, you can simply call `self.hits()` in your subscribe function to access the value. The brackets are necessary since it is an observable.

Comment: Okay I can now get the value but how do I change it to 10 and update the input field with the new number ?

Comment: You simply need to throw the new value into it: `self.hits(10);` I recommend you to follow the [interactive tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/) to get a better understanding of Knockout.